# Angular.js: Data binding not working with directives controller option

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

Why is angular's data binding not working when I specify a controller in the directives controller option? `$scope.emailInvalid.text` normally should get mapped to `type.text` but in my case, nothing get's displayed.

JS:

```
.directive('alert', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div>{{type.text}}</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            type: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.emailInvalid = {
                text: 'Text Alert Two'
            };
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<alert type="emailInvalid"></alert>
```

When I define a separate controller and pass it with `ng-controller` in the HTML, everything works like expected.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U4qvd8oK6hGj07A6VvBC?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to display `type.text` you need to define

```
$scope.type = {
    text: 'Text Alert Two'
};
```

in your *directive controller*. By doing so, you don't event have to pass the object to the *directive*.

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/0o4MX1zqv2BUx7tZhWoW?p=preview)

Comment: In my case it's important to pass the object into the directive, because there will be multiple kinds of alerts in my app which all use the same markup - just with a different text. I want to specify which text to use by defining the type as an attribute. See my updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U4qvd8oK6hGj07A6VvBC?p=preview). What I think is weird, is that the two controllers in my example are basically the same, but by defining one inside the directive with the directives controller option, the data binding with `scope : {type: '='}` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution:

The problem was that angular fails at mapping `$scope.emailInvalid` to `$scope.type`. What I have done in my example with `<alert type="emailInvalid"></alert>`, is passing an object `emailInvalid` to the directive. Angular is looking for this object in the scopes model of where I used the directive. Obviously this object doesn't exist and angular can't map anything.

The part I was missing is, that **the controller I defined with the directives controller option is defined in a different scope than the controller I used with `ng-controller`.**

To work around this problem I'm now passing a string instead of an object and use switch/case to map the alert type.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U4qvd8oK6hGj07A6VvBC?p=preview)